# How to not lose any MQTT messages

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am new to using MQTT. I have set up an Arduino publishing MQTT messages to ActiveMQ. I also have a Python script subscribed to the same topic (using paho) which gets the data from the broker and inserts it into a database.

The problem is if this Python script is down or loses connection for any reason I lose all messages being published while its down. How can I ensure all the data is inserted into the database?

Comment: An Arduino Uno has 32kB Flash, 2kB RAM and 1kB EEPROM.  That's pretty small for a "not lose any MQTT messages" IMHO. Maybe it can be estimated how many messages can be stored, given we know the payload size.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have an SD card storing sensor data in JSON format for the arduino. so all of the data is published to the broker. my worry is if the python client is not actively subscribes at the time of the publishing message I lose that data.

Comment: I suggest you do a little research into MQTT QOS and persistent sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that your subscription persists and receives messages even if the subscriber gets disconnected then you need to set CleanSession=false on your MQTT client (assuming you're using MQTT 3.x) and use the same client ID when you reconnect.

Also, if you want messages to survive a broker restart or crash you need to send them with QoS 1.

Comment: And subscribe with QOS 1+ (as the question relates to the python script that subscribes). The comment re QOS applies to all network outages. Its also worth noting that some clients written for low resource devices do not support publishing at QOS1+ ([e.g.](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient#limitations)).

Answer (score -1):

I think the PubSubClient Arduino library only publishes with fire and forget (QoS 0). I've instead used the stomp.py library to create a durable consumer subscribed to the same topic. If there's no connection on Arduino It's saved to the SD card and if there is connection but no client at the time the messages are stored by ActiveMQ until the client is active.

This solved my problem but I'm still testing the durability